# SharePoint document library problem using .config extension

Tags: sharepoint, file, config

If I upload files with the .config extension to a SharePoint document library, clicking on them from a browser gives me the message:

XML Parsing Error: no element found
  Location: https://www...........somefile.config
  Line Number 1, Column 1:

Also, if I view the document library using "Open with Windows Explorer" I am unable to view or copy any of the .config files.  I consistently get a "file not found" type error. 
Note that if I add a .txt file to this document library, it works fine.  I defined the MIME type for .config, and now I get 404 errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The file extension is a configuration file extension. IIS prevents downloading files with this extension to prevent security breaches

Comment: Not true.  If I click on the SharePoint drop down for a file with a .config extension, I can "Send To | Download a Copy...".  With that I am able to download the file.  

The issue appears only when I attempt to click on the file, or retrieve it using the Windows Explorer view of a SharePoint library.

Comment: This extension is blocked by default, did you unblock it?